# Chartjs 4 - Fill area between stacked line and bar chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm in the process of migrating over to chart.js 4.4.1 and in the prior version (2.9.4) I was able to fill the gap with a color as in the attached image.

[2.9.4 sample img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkCaq.png)

In the newest version, I'm able to get close by using an opacity, but it's not quite the same:
[4.4.1 sample img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqrCk.png)

Any ideas on how to make that happen? I'm using the non-module JavaScript chartjs file.

See my test code below.

```
<canvas id="my-chart"></canvas>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.1/chart.umd.js"></script>
    <script>
        
        let labels = [];
        for (let year=2000; year <= 2010; year++) {
            labels.push(year);
        }

        const config = {
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        type: "bar",
                        label: "Product",
                        data: [1331320,2851137,5952127,6607851,11068289,12059067,12117998,11827962,16582836,20184478,23915606],
                        backgroundColor: "#bec38f",
                        order: 1
                    },
                    {
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(151,156,106,0.5)",// "#979c6a",
                        borderColor: "#826f68",
                        borderWidth: 3,
                        data: [1242306,2442693,5070218,5502960,8572948,7722718,6916448,7196356,10429229,12544283,15149568],
                        label: "Benchmark",
                        type: "line",
                        fill: true,
                        pointBackgroundColor: "#ffffff",
                        pointRadius: 5,
                        order: 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    x: {
                        grid: {
                            display: false
                        }
                    },
                    y: {
                        stacked: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: false
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
                                return ("$" + (value/1000000));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                plugins: {
                    tooltip: {
                        intersect: true,
                        callbacks: {
                            label: function(context) {
                                return ("$" + context.parsed.y.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        new Chart(document.getElementById("my-chart"), config);

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the drawTime of the filler plugin to `beforeDatasetsDraw` by adding the following config to the plugins section of the config object:

```js
filler: {
  drawTime: 'beforeDatasetsDraw'
},
```

Live example:

```js
let labels = [];
for (let year = 2000; year <= 2010; year++) {
  labels.push(year);
}

const config = {
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
        type: "bar",
        label: "Product",
        data: [1331320, 2851137, 5952127, 6607851, 11068289, 12059067, 12117998, 11827962, 16582836, 20184478, 23915606],
        backgroundColor: "#bec38f",
        order: 1
      },
      {
        backgroundColor: "#979c6a",
        borderColor: "#826f68",
        borderWidth: 3,
        data: [1242306, 2442693, 5070218, 5502960, 8572948, 7722718, 6916448, 7196356, 10429229, 12544283, 15149568],
        label: "Benchmark",
        type: "line",
        fill: true,
        pointBackgroundColor: "#ffffff",
        pointRadius: 5,
        order: 0
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          display: false
        }
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
            return ("$" + (value / 1000000));
          }
        }
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      filler: {
        drawTime: 'beforeDatasetsDraw'
      },
      tooltip: {
        intersect: true,
        callbacks: {
          label: function(context) {
            return ("$" + context.parsed.y.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

new Chart(document.getElementById("my-chart"), config);
```

```html
<canvas id="my-chart"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.1/chart.umd.js"></script>
```

[Documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.4.1/charts/area.html#configuration)